# How do you allow a fav icon to show in all versions of IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, icons, favicon

How do you allow a fav icon to show in all versions of IE?
I have fav icons that has been inserted in the root and sub-directory within the website. It will display in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. However, it will not display in any versions of IE (I have test IE 8 and 9 with changing the environments between earlier versions using the compatibility feature). How do I make this work?

I am using this code in my html  and  tags:

```
<head>
     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.domain.com/icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
     <link rel="icon" href="http://www.domain.com/icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
```

I have research related questions on Stack Overflow as well as outside sources and they agree on the implementation used in my HTML. I am wondering what the problem could be.

Comment: This question may be possible duplicate of [122067][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122067/favicon-not-working-in-ie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Your favicon.ico must be placed between head tag
   size : 16x16 + 32x32, colors: 256colors and 32-bit
    and for Internet Explorer it must be transparent (the outer white part should not visible)