# Favicon Icon NOT shown on IE 9

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, .net, vb.net

Favicon icon is showing at chrome, mozilla firefox and i tried other browsers too but it is not showing in IE 9. I am unable to locate where the problem is.

I pasted the code below inside head tag inside MasterPage(using Visual Studio)

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <title>DemoPage</title>
    <link href="css/patrika.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

But favicon is still not shown in IE 9. Is there any other way to do it.. or i am doing something wrong because it works very well on other browsers - chrome,firefox..

Comment: try copying favicon.ico into the root of your website (rather than the subfolder images)  and it should work automagically ;o)

Comment: Pretty sure favicons are expected in the root, never tried to override this personally. And in that case, you don't even need a hard reference.

Comment: i tried to put inside the root directory, it didn't works..! :(

Comment: possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739918/how-do-you-allow-a-fav-icon-to-show-in-all-versions-of-ie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122067/favicon-not-working-in-ie you could also check things links. This could also help you :).

Comment: There used to be an IE "feature" that it only showed favicons for *bookmarked* sites. I don't know if that still applies?

Comment: This thread [favicon not showing in IE8](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/a6fb09ef-aa3e-4e9e-be44-edbfad322657/) may be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well guys!
Thanks for your answer and support!!

I got the solution now
We have to add like this inside head tag

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favi.ico" type="text/x-html-insertion" />
```

Favicon is now working in IE 9 too.
Hope this will going to helpful at your end in future as well.

Answer (score 3):

For the most consistent results, use an absolute path to the favicon.ico file in your domain root folder:

```
<link href="//yourdomain/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Other cases you have to check as well are:
1. Are you renaming a jpg to ico? If so, create the file as an ico and it will wok as expected.
2. If the site is a closed one and requires log in, the icon will not be displayed. Add an exception for the favicon.ico in the web.config:

```
<location path="favicon.ico">
  <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow users="*" />
     </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Your parenthetical remark could be handled implicitly by: `<link href="//yourdomain.com/favicon.ico"`.

Comment: Or a [protocol-less URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831741/can-i-change-all-my-http-links-to-just) - `href="//yourdomain/favicon.ico"` should cater for both

Answer (score 1):

Look at the acces log file of your webbrowser. You can actually see where the various browsers do look for a favicon.ico file, then put it there were IE9 is looking for it.

Some browsers were notoriously hard to trigger re-reading the favicon.ico file if they had not done so on first try. So make sure you see that it is trying to retrieve, including restarting the browser and if necessary clearing its cache.

Comment: i tried to re-open the browser after removing all cache contents by pressing Ctrl+F5 . but still not working. :(

Comment: And what do you see in the log file? Did you see IE9 accessing favicon.ico?

Answer (score 0):

Use full path for icon

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.yourdomain.com/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Just refresh the page or delete the cache and refresh it there is no difference between browsers for favicon.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but it was not clear (to me) from your answer that you were talking about his code.

Comment: I'm with you in that sorry.