# How can I check to see if my favicon file is valid for IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, favicon

My favicon works fine in FF, Chrome and Safari but not IE.  All are modern versions, but I don't have exact version numbers.

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' href = '../images/favicon.png'>
```

It appears that in 2008 , IE was more particular ( [see SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122067/favicon-not-working-in-ie) ).

[Google search here.](https://www.google.com/#q=favicon+does+not+display+in+IE)

However, is there anyway I can troubleshoot my missing favicon further.  Is IE the only browser that has a problem with .png files.  Did they continue this tradition of difficulty in 2016?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing with?

Comment: you might want to add a `type=image/png` attrib for better compat when not using an ico file

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your favicon file is a .ico file, that is my best guess. Check out this web tool to convert files --> http://www.favicon-generator.org/

Answer (score 1):

You use a PNG icon, declared as if it was an old fashion ICO icon (`rel="shortcut icon"`, no `type` attribute).

You should combine the old ICO and "modern" PNG formats to get the job done everywhere. For example:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/path/to/icons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/path/to/icons/favicon.ico">
```

I suggest you to use [Real Favicon Generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net), which generates the icons and the corresponding HTML code. Full disclosure: I'm the author of this site.