# What are the valid favicon types for IE10+?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, favicon

By type I mean file extension.

My favicon works for FF, Chrome, and Safari, and someone suggested in might be the favicon type that is causing the issue.

More generally is there a good resource online that would give me this information?

I am more interested in finding accurate documentation than simply trying different types.

I would prefer to use a .svg file if possible an not a raster image.  Also, I do not have a way to generate .ico files as I'm using Inkscape.

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' href = '../images/favicon.png'>
```

**Research**

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon

[favicon not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122067/favicon-not-working-in-ie)

Please note that I don not want to put it in the root folder.

According to the spec I'm breaking the spec so IE will work.

In actuality I'm breaking the spec for IE to work and it still does not work.

Why does it hate me?

Answer (score 1):

This are the favicon `types` you can use everywhere:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/favicon.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="http://example.com/favicon.gif" />
```

A complete list of favicons can be something like this:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-128.png" sizes="128x128" />
<meta name="application-name" content="Site"/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-144x144.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="/mstile-70x70.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="/mstile-150x150.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="/mstile-310x150.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="/mstile-310x310.png" />
```

See more info [here](https://css-tricks.com/favicon-quiz/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but can you provide a reference so I can now where I am supposed to get this information from ?

Comment: Can I still use my relative link or do I have to change it to absolute?

Comment: yes relative is fine, was just an example, see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Go to [enter link description here](https://realfavicongenerator.net/) Once you upload a 260px X 260 px image the site creates all the various favicons and code. Then on tablets and moobile devices when you save the bookmark it looks like an app icon on your device
example https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker?site=http%3A%2F%2Fnationalkitchencabinets.com%2F&ignore_root_issues=on#.V0yL-77PSSo

The page will give you code like this to post in the '' top section of your page. Then place ALL the icons it gives you into the root of the website.

```javascript
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Answer (score 0):

ICO file format is represented by Microsoft in the first versions of Windows and is generally not a format for images, but a container for BMP and PNG images. So it actually is supposed to contain BMP/PNG images inside, well, at least one.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29

You can find a table of supported image formats for "Favicon" here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

**SVG is supported on FF 41.0+ only. ( on theory )**

The main idea behind the ISO format is to pack the image icons in different sizes: 16x16px ( which is the main, used as Favicon in the browsers) , 32x32, 64x64 and so on into one file, so this "ICO"n to look nice on different resolutions. You can easy find tons of online tools which convert almost any format to ICO, but almost all of them will create only one image in most cases 16x16px.

Comment: Also, just a note about the /favicon.ico path, most browsers are reading the HTML tag and find the path from it which is fine, but, some search engines like yandex ( and many robots) are trying to open directly the favicon from  http://domain.com/favicon.ico and will not be able to index the favicon of your page properly.