# Custom favicon not showing in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, https, cross-browser

The below code is working in all the browsers execpt `IE`. Someone said that if you are accessing the page using (`https://`) without the certificate then it will not work.

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Can certificate errors (`https`) prevent the  custom favicon from appearing?

Comment: Are you loading the webpage over HTTPS? Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122067/favicon-not-working-in-ie for other potential causes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [favicon not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122067/favicon-not-working-in-ie)