# Favicon icon not shown on IE11

Tags: html

- I have a favicon image generated that I would like to display in IE 11 but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get it to display in IE 11.
- I used a favicon generator at XXX to create my `32x32 favicon` image then uploaded it to YYY where I generated the final favicon.ico image file comprising I expect the image in four different sizes.
- I then uploaded the favicon.ico image file to my server's root directory.
- I inserted the `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../Resouce/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />` in the  tag pair in my index.html file and uploaded it to my server's root directory. But when I load my home page in IE 11 no favicon is displayed. I am stumped. I have tried clearing my browser cache but still no joy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [favicon not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122067/favicon-not-working-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some code, and have you tried:

```
<link rel="icon" href=" - path to your favicon.ico - " type="image/x-icon"     />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="- path to your favicon.ico -" type="image/x-icon" />
```

or this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
```

Comment: www.yourpage.com means

Comment: <link rel="shortcut icon"  href="../Resource/images/favicon.ico"/>

Comment: Yeah still nothing or  ?

Comment: <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../Resource/images/favicon.ico"/>

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
   <title>XXXXX</title>
    <%--<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../Resource/images/favicon.ico"/>--%>
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">; <html xmlns="w3.org/1999/xhtml">; <head id="Head1" runat="server"> <title>XXXXX</title> <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../Resource/images/favicon.ico"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">

Comment: out of anwser then sorry

Comment: btw the first 2 link should both be in your header not only one of them

Comment: <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://10.50.17.8/Kezava1.2_DevExp17/Resource/Images/favicon.ico"/>    it works in chrome and mozilla but not in IE11